# Order of magnitude of a float in Julia 1.6

Tags: julia

Is there a way to determine the order of magnitude of a float in Julia 1.6?

For instance, a function such that `OrderOfMagnitude(1000) = 3`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various definitions of order of magnitude, some of them are (assuming `x` is positive):

- `floor(Int, log10(x))`
- `floor(Int, log10(2*x))`
- `floor(Int, log10(sqrt(10)*x))`